Change in Chromes Rendering of Chunked Responses
I have a service that returns large lists of data (JSON).
The list is transfered using chunked encoding to make data available to the client as soon as its there.
During development, I tend to load that list using Chrome and I can see items arriving one by one as I would expect. At least I used to. Now, (current version is 130.0.6723.92) this does no longer happen. Instead, the browser window remains empty until the entire response has arrived and only then the entire list gets displayed.
I'm not sure when this happened, but it's annoying! When opening the developer tools, and selecting "Preview" or "Response" in the Network tab, I can clearly see the data streaming in. The Transfer-Encoding header is also set correctly. It seems to really only be a rendering issue.
I have googled quite a bit but seem to be alone with this issue.
Could this have something to do with the relatively new option to "pretty print" JSON using the checkbox underneath the adress bar?
Is there some secret setting I can change to restore the "old" behavior?
Best Regards

Can you reproduce in other browsers? Are you sure it's not the server that changed? Btw. "chunked encoding" is only a thing under HTTP/1. In HTTP/2 and 3, the header has no effect and the streaming happens in the transport layer.

Edge behaves the same way as Chrome. But I don't know how that behaved previously in there. I've considered the HTTP/2 issue and forced HTTP/1.1 on the server side: same Issue. Don't have firefox or anything else installed at the moment.
There have been no code changes that would affect this, but just to be sure i've created an empty ASP.NET service with just a single endpoint that simulates similar response streaming. Same behavior (and i know for a fact that this exact code behaved differently before).
